# usepackage unicode-math led to insufficient symbol font errors

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I'm working on a Chinese-English hybrid document. Previously I'm using pdflatex to build, but now have changed to xelatex in order to change math fonts.

However, many errors popped up when I try to change the fonts. My document is built well using both pdflatex and xelatex. But when I add the following content:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
```

Many errors popped up, like this:

```
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. \maketitle
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. \maketitle
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. \contentsline {chapter}{序言}{1}{chapter*.5}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. \contentsline {chapter}{序言}{1}{chapter*.5}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...一章\hspace {0.3em}}引言}{3}{chapter.1}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...rline {1.1}问题的提出}{3}{section.1.1}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...下的发展与变化}{3}{subsection.1.1.1}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...复用的分类}{3}{subsubsection.1.1.1.1}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...的发展趋势}{3}{subsubsection.1.1.1.2}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...}软件资源分类研究}{3}{section.1.2}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...类与）概况}{3}{subsubsection.1.2.0.1}
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...和难点/新问题}}{4}{subsection.1.2.1}
```

The building progress finished eventually, and it did generate a readable pdf file without some math contents.

[image]

I have no idea of why these errors come up. I'm not quite familiar with LaTeX, and I am using a template by others. Who can help me with this problem?

=====================================

Supplement 1: Thanks to advices from @egreg.  I put up a minimal example that triggers this error.

Except the above error, this code also triggered some undefined control sequence error.

```
\documentclass[UTF8, colorlinks]{pkuthss}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} 
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

I have checked the original error log again, found that many errors occur in `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents`, also found:

```
Command \@footnotemark has changed.
Font shape `T1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead'
Font shape `T1/LatinModernMath(0)/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead
Font shape `T1/LatinModernRoman(0)/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n' instead
Font shape `T1/LatinModernMath(1)/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead
```

I guess that something in the pkuthss class file might be the causes. However there was no error before I use the `/setmathfont` order.

=====================================

Supplement 2: code in the template file(document class)

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \cleardoublepage
    % Add PDF bookmark for the title page.
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\titlepagename}{titlepage}
    \begin{titlepage}
        % It will be more nice to use this line skip level in the title page.
        \linespread{1.6}\selectfont
        % Make the title page centered.
        \begin{center}
            % Emblem and inscription of the university, and type of thesis.
            {
                \zihao{1}%
                \includegraphics[height = 2.4em]{pkulogo}\hspace{0.4em}%
                \raisebox{0.4em}{\includegraphics[height = 1.6em]{pkuword}}\\[0.8em]
                {\bfseries{\cthesisname}}
            }
            \vfill
            % Title of the thesis.
            {
                \zihao{2}{\label@ctitle}%
                \pkuthss@int@fillinblank{2}{0.64\textwidth}{\textbf{\@ctitle}}
            }
            \vfill
            % Information about the author.
            {
                % Slightly adjust the line skip when using new font size.
                \zihao{-2}\linespread{1.75}\selectfont
                \def\pkuthss@tmp@len{0.56\textwidth}
                \begin{tabular}{l@{\extracolsep{0.2em}}c}
                    {\label@cauthor}        &
                    \pkuthss@int@fillinblank{1}{\pkuthss@tmp@len}{\kaishu\@cauthor}     \\
                    {\label@studentid}  &
                    \pkuthss@int@fillinblank{1}{\pkuthss@tmp@len}{\kaishu\@studentid}   \\
                    {\label@school}         &
                    \pkuthss@int@fillinblank{1}{\pkuthss@tmp@len}{\kaishu\@school}      \\
                    {\label@cmajor}         &
                    \pkuthss@int@fillinblank{1}{\pkuthss@tmp@len}{\kaishu\@cmajor}      \\
                    {\label@direction}  &
                    \pkuthss@int@fillinblank{1}{\pkuthss@tmp@len}{\kaishu\@direction}   \\
                    {\label@cmentor}        &
                    \pkuthss@int@fillinblank{1}{\pkuthss@tmp@len}{\kaishu\@cmentor}     \\
                \end{tabular}
            }
            \vfill
            % Date.
            {\kaishu\zihao{2}\@date}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
}
```

=============================

supplement 3:

I found that if I'm not using the unicode-math package, and only add the `\setmainfont` order, the file will build and present normally. So I guess that's not an issue related to the fonts?

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

=========================

supplement 4:

I have another minimal example to generate the error:

```
\documentclass[UTF8, colorlinks]{pkuthss}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
test：$d=\left\langle t_1, t_2, \dots , t_T\right\rangle $\\
corpus：$c=\left\lbrace d_1, d_2, \dots, d_D \right\rbrace $\\
\end{document}
```

The errors are:

```
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. test：$d
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...angle t_1, t_2, \dots , t_T\right\rangle $
Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. ...brace d_1, d_2, \dots, d_D \right\rbrace $
```

If I change the first line to this, there will be no error. So what should I post from the pkuthss class file?

```
\documentclass[UTF8, colorlinks]{article}
```

Also I have noticed some warnings before the error:

```
Font shape `T1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead
```

===============================

supplement 5:

updated to the latest version.

I have updated the pkuthss class file to the latest version, on https://github.com/CasperVector/pkuthss , as suggested by @Mico.
Unfortunately, the errors are still there...

When I try to build the minimal example in supplement 4, the same messages still popped up.

I feel so frustrated... Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a minimal example of code producing the error, starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Thanks for your remind! But I'm using a complex template to organize my document. I have checked the errors and found that they all occured in the predefined document-class code... as in the \maketitle or \tableofcontents parts... It's a little hard for me to separate the "minimal example"...

Comment: @egreg  I extracted the following code to generate the above error, also with some undefined control sequence error.  I guess that would be something in the pkuthss class file matters... `\documentclass[UTF8, colorlinks]{pkuthss}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}`

Comment: Please, supplement the question, rather than adding code in comments.

Comment: @egreg thank you for advices, I have supplemented the question.

Comment: I think we will need a link to the class file. `\maketitle` gives an error because you haven't defined a title or author. Probably. Only the class will tell you. But always post the exact text of error messages: *which* control sequence is undefined is the obvious question. LaTeX will have told you. In general, only the first error is worth worrying about at one time. Nothing after an error is reliable, even - indeed, especially - further errors.

Comment: @cfr thanks. In the original text and supplement 4, I have posted the exact log, the first few lines. And author info should not be the issue here, since my document contains the complete info and compiled normally before I introduced the font change. I just extract the "minimal" snippet as suggested by egreg. So you mentioned the class file, I also guess that something in it does not coorperate well with the unicode-math. But the class file is so long, I posted the maketitle part in supplement 2. What else should I post here, in your opinion?

Comment: Provide a link to the class. Your minimal example should reproduce the error you need help with. If it produces the wrong error, it isn't helpful. But without the class, nobody can reproduce the problem anyway.

Comment: @cfr it does produce exact the error I got. Here is the onedrive link for the class file : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjYQ69nPowYqgqFzPYbmL5dE6rAHeQ   thank you very much.

Comment: I don't get the class. Just a blank page with the path at the top and the header. Someone else may have better luck.

Comment: That said, I wouldn't use any class which redefines `\maketitle` like that. I've seen worse, but then most of the definition is meaningless without other bits. It isn't responsible for the symbol font errors, though.

Comment: If you expect us to help you in a meaningful way, it's not enough to post a link to `pkuthss.cls`. It's also essential to provide links to `pkuthss-extra.sty`, `pkuthss-utf8.def`, and `pkuthss-gbk.def`. Having access to `pkulogo.eps`, and `pkuword.eps` would be help, too. Maybe post a link to a webpage that acts as a repository for these files? Might `https://github.com/CasperVector/pkuthss` just be such a webpage?

Comment: Incidentally, the version information of `pkuthss.cls` in the link you provided is "1.5.4 (2014/07/04)"; in contrast, the version number on Casper Vector's GitHub site is "1.7.3 (2016/05/24)". It may well be the case that the latest versions of the `pkuthss*.*` files contain important bug fixes. Please test out your code with the latest versions of all files and, in particular, check whether the error(s) you've encountered and have reported above persist.

Comment: @cfr - It turns out that the OP is using deprecated versions of the `pkuthss*.*` files. (See the other comments I posted.) It may well be the case that simply updating to the latest version fixes the OP's issues.

Comment: @Mico thanks so much for the information. I didn't notice that there's a github site for this template. I'll try the latest version and then post the results.

Comment: @Mico The update doesn't work... I have supplemented the question.

Comment: Sorry, but with the `pkuthss` class in TeX Live, the fourth supplement compiles for me.

Comment: @egreg I am using tex live too, and using text studio as editor. I guess some configurations might go wrong? I have changed two pc and both failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question after consulting the author of pkuthss.cls.

Following his advice, there are two way to solve my problem.

1. It's not necessary to use packge unicode-math to meet my requirement of changing math font. Two optional approach:

   a) Use document class with a parameter `nopkufont`: `\documentclass[UTF8, nopkufont]{pkuthss}` . The current font style are according to the regulations of our university, negate the parameter to use traditional latex font(latexsym).

   b) Change the cls file content:

> ```
>    \ifpkuthss@opt@pkufont
>       % Use Times New Roman / Arial according to school regulation.
>       % Option used to prevent newtxtext from manipulating footnote marks.
>       \RequirePackage[defaultsups]{newtxtext}
>       \RequirePackage{newtxmath}
>     \else
>       % Provides `\Box' for originauth.tex if newtx is absent.
>       \RequirePackage{latexsym}
>     \fi
> ```

Delete the line of  `\RequirePackage{newtxmath}` will change the font of math contents to latin modern math without violating the PKU regulations.

You can use the above two solutions at the same time, that's what I did since no matter in which case I would like to use latin modern math as the math font and I might have to change the normal text to the newtx font if asked by the university.

2. If sticking to the unicode-math package, reinstalltion has solved my problem.

Also noticed @egreg did not reproduce my errors, so there might be something wrong in my configuration of tex. As suggested by the author, I uninstalled the tex live and re-install the latest tex live version following the bootstrap guide given by the author (https://bbs.pku.edu.cn/attach/boards/MathTools/M.1435670549.A/pkuthss-bootstrap-0.1.5-r1.pdf?t=1464095057, in Chinese) (not too much changes compared with the normal installation progress).

After re-installation, my errors disappeared... I don't know why and how...

Anyway, my problem has been solved. I think this is such a specific issue only related to the thesis template of our university, may not be helpful to others. Anyway I posted the answer here, in case another PKU student encountered the same problem...